# How does GNOME files implement the copy dialog?

Tags: gnome, nautilus

For simple tasks I use GNOME files (Nautilus) to copy files rather than rsync. I tried digging through the source [nautilus-file-operations.c](https://github.com/GNOME/nautilus/blob/76d3107809cd3484eb7fde5b1f6d63f21d5309b9/src/nautilus-file-operations.c#L5054) which I am not familiar with, and I assume it uses its own custom implementation (not `cp`) for error handling and to `report_copy_progress`? I have no idea where the actual system calls take place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe all GNOME file operations use GFiles, which according to the [description](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GFile.html):

> GFile is a high level abstraction for manipulating files on a virtual file system. GFiles are lightweight, immutable objects that do no I/O upon creation. It is necessary to understand that GFile objects do not represent files, merely an identifier for a file. All file content I/O is implemented as streaming operations (see GInputStream and GOutputStream).

So the I/O is really implemented in [ginputstream.c](https://github.com/GNOME/glib/blob/master/gio/ginputstream.c) and [goutputstream.c](https://github.com/GNOME/glib/blob/master/gio/goutputstream.c), in functions like [g_input_stream_read](https://github.com/GNOME/glib/blob/a656555f76f1b5666d1210e4a6a02b1f3d619aec/gio/ginputstream.c#L127-L206), but this relies on some read function GInputStreamClass [`class->read_fn`](https://github.com/GNOME/glib/blob/a656555f76f1b5666d1210e4a6a02b1f3d619aec/gio/ginputstream.c#L198), which varies based on if the program is streaming from a socket, local file, win32 file, pollable stream, etc. (my guess)

For local files (I can't actually find the definition of local file, but I assume it's a file from disk) in `g_local_file_input_stream_read` we finally find the syscall `read` [on line 158](https://github.com/GNOME/glib/blob/cbfa776fc149fcc3e351fbdf68c1a299519f4905/gio/glocalfileinputstream.c#L158):

```c
static gssize
g_local_file_input_stream_read (GInputStream  *stream,
                void          *buffer,
                gsize          count,
                GCancellable  *cancellable,
                GError       **error)
{
  GLocalFileInputStream *file;
  gssize res;

  file = G_LOCAL_FILE_INPUT_STREAM (stream);

  res = -1;
  while (1)
    {
      if (g_cancellable_set_error_if_cancelled (cancellable, error))
    break;
      res = read (file->priv->fd, buffer, count);
      if (res == -1)
    {
          int errsv = errno;

      if (errsv == EINTR)
        continue;

      g_set_error (error, G_IO_ERROR,
               g_io_error_from_errno (errsv),
               _("Error reading from file: %s"),
               g_strerror (errsv));
    }

      break;
    }

  return res;
}
```

Similarly the [`write` call](https://github.com/GNOME/glib/blob/c1a15894e4206fd41839dc4b5bbd157ea3754e28/gio/glocalfileoutputstream.c#L199) in `g_local_file_output_stream_write`:

```c
static gssize
g_local_file_output_stream_write (GOutputStream  *stream,
                  const void     *buffer,
                  gsize           count,
                  GCancellable   *cancellable,
                  GError        **error)
{
  GLocalFileOutputStream *file;
  gssize res;

  file = G_LOCAL_FILE_OUTPUT_STREAM (stream);

  while (1)
    {
      if (g_cancellable_set_error_if_cancelled (cancellable, error))
    return -1;
      res = write (file->priv->fd, buffer, count);
      if (res == -1)
    {
          int errsv = errno;

      if (errsv == EINTR)
        continue;

      g_set_error (error, G_IO_ERROR,
               g_io_error_from_errno (errsv),
               _("Error writing to file: %s"),
               g_strerror (errsv));
    }

      break;
    }

  return res;
}
```